# Need a script to overlay information from MySQL database on background image and export as PDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, download, export

So, here's the issue. We are creating a Marketing Center where people can go and pull flyers from and then put their information on this flyer, then save the flyer with their info. The current setup is just a repository with editable PDFs, but we just received word that editable PDFs are not allowed and we have to come up with a way to automatically generate the flyers for each person.

Here's how I'd like it to work:

The script pulls the selected flyers' JPEG image from a database, pulls whoever is logged in's contact information from our existing MySQL database, places their information in a specific part of the flyer (bottom center), and then exports this whole thing as a PDF for download.

We're not sure how to go about this. If there are current tools available to do such a thing, that'd be awesome, but we can also work from scratch.

Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

With [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org) library you cal open pdf document, add some text and give it to user. Or you can create empty PDF document, add an image, text and so on.